# Is there any way to recreate an object from the output of its Object.inspect method?

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch, marshalling, logstash

While working with the open source ELK stack, we have run into an issue where one of the Logstash inputs snmptrap is formatting data in a way that is unusable for us. Within the [SNMPv1_Trap](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/hallidave/ruby-snmp/SNMP/SNMPv1_Trap) class there is an instance variable called `agent_address` which is stored as a [SNMP::IpAddress](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/hallidave/ruby-snmp/SNMP/IpAddress). For anyone familiar with the way SNMP works, the agent address is extremely important in determining where a SNMP trap originated from when using trap relays on your network.

The problem can be seen when you take a look at an event generated by Logstash upon receiving a trap. Mainly, the `inspect` method of the `agent_address` variable is dumping data that does not match anything valid.

A sample event looks kind of like this:

```
#<SNMP::SNMPv1_Trap:0x2db53346 @enterprise=[1.3.6.1.4.1.6827.10.17.3.1.1.1], @timestamp=#<SNMP::TimeTicks:0x2a643dd1 @value=0>, @varbind_list=[#<SNMP::VarBind:0x2d5043a5 @name=[1.0], @value=#<SNMP::Integer:0x29fb6a4a @value=1>>], @specific_trap=1000, @source_ip=\"192.168.87.228\", @agent_addr=#<SNMP::IpAddress:0x227a4011 @value=\"\\xC0\\xA8V\\xFE\">, @generic_trap=6>
```

We know however, that the IpAddress object used in SNMP::SNMPv1_Trap is able to return us a nicely formatted string representing the IPv4 address it is storing.

For example:

```
require 'snmp'
include SNMP
address = IpAddress.new(192.168.86.254)
puts address
```

will yield `192.168.86.254` whereas:

```
require 'snmp'
include SNMP
address = IpAddress.new(192.168.86.254)
puts address.inspect
```

will yield:

```
#<SNMP::IpAddress:0x0000000168ae88 @value="\xC0\xA8V\xFE">
```

This is the expected behaviour of an object whose `.inspect` method has not been overridden.

Obviously the IPv4 address in @value is not useful to us, it has only three valid hex sequences (xC0=192, xA8=168, xFE=254) and also contains an invalid hex sequence ('V'). The same thing occurs whenever an octet string representing an IPv4 address is sent as a variable binding as well, which suggests some strange encoding.

Unfortunately, aside from writing our own SNMP input, there is no interface level access to this object. The object we receive via 'event' contains the inspect string, not the object itself. Therefore, the easiest apparent way to get the information we need would be to reconstruct the SNMPv1_Trap object and then make our own calls to it via `Object.#send`.

If I have the raw, unformatted and default string dump returned by `Object.#inspect`, is there any way to physically recreate the object used to make this inspect dump on the fly?

For example, given the string dump:

```
#<Integer:0x2737476 @value=1>
```

is it possible to recreate an Integer object with a field whose value is 1?. If this is possible, is there also a way to recreate nested objects the same way? For example, given the string:

```
#<SNMP::SNMPv1_Trap:0x2ef73621 @value=1, @agent_address=#<SNMP::IpAddress:0x0000000168ae88 @value="\xC0\xA8V\xFE">>
```

Would it possible to have an object that looks like the following?

```
SNMP::SNMPv1_Trap{
  @value : 1
  @agent_address : SNMP::IpAddress{
      @value : 1
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't answer your question (thus the comment), but we recently replaced our snmptrap inputs (handled by a separate, smaller logstash that put them into redis for resiliency) with snmptrapd.  It gave us more flexibility in the processing and removed the need for redis.

Comment: Welcome to SO. We don't care if you're new to SO or a language, we just expect you to do your research and show us your effort. Please read "[ask]" including the links at the bottom, and "[mcve]".

Comment: If they didn't implement the `inspect` method for the class, why don't you? You can overwrite methods in many different ways. And, in our experience at work, SNMP MIBs are all over the place as far as completeness and accuracy. We've had them returning raw/binary data requiring me to write code to tear apart the structure and turn it back into usable information.

Comment: If an object's state is completely determined by its instance variables (no globals, no entries in some hash class variable, nothing else weird), and the `inspect` output contains all of those values, yes, you can reconstruct an object with identical values (not the *same* object, however).

Comment: Something else -- if you have the inspect string of an object that is still "alive" (not been garbage collected, still has references somewhere), you could do (though it would be woefully inefficient, don't use for production) an `ObjectSpace.each_object(SNMP::SNMPv1_Trap)` search looking for the object with the matching address in its inspect string (at least, for current versions of YARV, I think it's an address).

Comment: (Sorry for all the comments). Note that the `@value` string you call "useless" contains the full IP address as a binary string, and can be easily converted back to numbers: `"\xC0\xA8V\xFE".unpack('CCCC')` --> `[192, 168, 86, 254]`. This (I think) solves your root problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I have the raw, unformatted and default string dump returned by `Object#inspect`, is there any way to physically recreate the object used to make this inspect dump on the fly?

No. `inspect` is intended for debugging purposes to be read by humans.

It is not guaranteed to be machine-readable. It is not guaranteed to be the same across different Ruby versions. It is not guaranteed to be the same across different Ruby implementations. It isn't even guaranteed to be the same across different versions of the same Ruby implementation implementing the same Ruby version. Heck, I don't even think it is guaranteed to be the same across two runs!

It is not a serialization format.

There are plenty of serialization formats specifically for Ruby (`Marshal`) or generically (XML, YAML, JSON, and of course ASN.1), but `inspect` isn't it.